# retrieving apple contacts using web call

Tags: icloud

Is there a way to retrieve apple contacts like how you can get someone's gmail contacts with their API.  Does apple have some kind of API for a web call using oauth or something similar for retrieving contact info?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no such thing. Apple will never allow it, its too risky to let the browser access contacts.